# Configuring QGIS for external editor

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-python-console

The editor pane in the python console has a button "Open in External Editor".

How do I tell QGIS what program to use as the external editor?

Answer (score 3):

QGIS uses editor set in the operating system.
If you use Linux, you can set the VISUAL and EDITOR environment variables, for example to use vim as an external editor:

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
```

If you would like to set it permanent add these two lines above to the .bashrc file in your home directory. Replace *vim* with your favorite text editor (e.g. nano, pico, gedit, etc.).

On Windows you can set default application depending on the file extension. Here is an example:
https://www.howto-connect.com/make-notepad-as-default-text-editor-windows-10/

Comment: This works on Windows as well. Create a system environment variable called EDITOR and set it to something like `emacsclient` (or `vim`).

Comment: Or let QGis create that variable on startup via  Settings > Options > System > Environment